# VBA to sum a column of data based on a date range in a dynamic table and insert value in last row

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, datatable, range

I have a table that lists dates in the first column and linear feet (LF) in the third column. The  current code adds rows each time a button is pressed and inserts data in the first 5 columns of the new row. I'm having trouble writing a second function that establishes a date range based on the inputBox value of a start date and sums the LF from the start date to the bottom of the table. I can't figure out how to establish the starting row of the sum range as the row that contains the start date.

My first button's code which works is:

```
Private Sub cmdAddWeek_Click()

    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim tableName As ListObject
    Set tableName = ws.ListObjects("ProductTbl")
    
    'LF/Hour
    Dim addedRow As ListRow
    Set addedRow = tableName.ListRows.Add()
    Dim newRowLF As Long
    Dim newRowLFHr As Long
    
    'LF/Week
    Dim endWeek As String
    Dim wkTotal As Long
    Dim wkstrt As String
    
    'insert information
    With addedRow
    
    'input static info
    .Range(1) = Range("B2")
    .Range(2) = Range("B3")
    .Range(3) = Range("B4")
    .Range(4) = Range("B5")
    
    'find new row values and divide for LF/Hour
    newRowLF = Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row
    newRowLFHr = Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range(5) = Cells(newRowLF, 10) / Cells(newRowLFHr, 11)
```

The second button that I can't figure out is:

```
Private Sub cmdEndWeek_Click()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim tableName As ListObject
    Set tableName = ws.ListObjects("ProductTbl")
    Dim lastRow As Range
    Set lastRow = tableName.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)

    Dim strtRow As Long
    Dim endRow As Long
    Dim AvgLF As Variant
    Dim wkstrt As String
    Dim wkend As String

    'week start input
    wkstrt = InputBox("Please enter the start date of the week in '1/01/2024' format:", "Week Start")
    'week end input
    wkend = InputBox("Please enter the end date of the week in '1/01/2024' format:", "Week End")
    
    With tableName
    
    'strtRow = .Range(tableName).Find(wkstrt, Range("H2")).Row
    'endRow = .Range(tableName).Find(wkend, Range("H" & strtRow)).Row
    
    .Range(lastRow, C13) = wkstrt 'WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(strtRow, 10), Cells(endRow, 10)))
    
    End With
```